# getting the date for next weekday

Tags: python, date

Im checking if the current date is a weekday, if not I want to get the next weekday. Weekday is from Monday to Friday.

Here is what I have tried:

```
import time
from datetime import date,timedelta
dmy=time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")# getting the current date 
if dmy.strftime("%w") in set([6,7]): # checking if its a weekend( Sat/Sun) , if so advancing
    dmy=time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")+ timedelta(days=dmy.strftime("%w")%5) # this statement is not working, it errors out .
```

The statement `dmy=time.strftime("%d-%m-%Y")+ timedelta(days=dmy.strftime("%w")%5)`) is not working. what is the easiest way to advance to the next date which is a weekday ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use actual `date` objects, not strings:

```
>>> import datetime
>>> today = datetime.date.today()
>>> if today.isoweekday() in set((6, 7)):
    today += datetime.timedelta(days=today.isoweekday() % 5)


>>> today
datetime.date(2014, 9, 30)
```

Note that [`isoweekday`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoweekday) is `1` (Monday) to `7` (Sunday), whereas [`weekday`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.weekday) is `0` to `6`.

---

Also, note that your logic currently adds one day to Saturday and two days to Sunday, which isn't correct - I think you want:

```
>>> if today.isoweekday() in set((6, 7)):
    today += datetime.timedelta(days=8 - today.isoweekday())
```

For example:

```
>>> day = datetime.date(2014, 10, 4)
>>> day
datetime.date(2014, 10, 4) # Saturday
>>> if day.isoweekday() in set((6, 7)):
    day += datetime.timedelta(days=8 - day.isoweekday())


>>> day
datetime.date(2014, 10, 6) # Monday
```

Comment: Now time has passed, I'd considering editing your answer @jonrsharpe simply because it starts with a correction of the incorrect code, which might lead to the less perceptive half-reading and applying the suggestion. While I agree it is to some extent their own fault for not reading, it might be helpful to simply include the answer so no context is needed to see what the answer should be.

Comment: Missing `5` in `set((6,7))`?

Comment: @GustavoLouisG.Montańo no, 5 is already a weekday per the OP's requirements

Answer (score 3):

```
def calculate_the_next_week_day(day_now):    
    if day_now.isoweekday()== 5:
        day_now += datetime.timedelta(days=3)
    elif day_now.isoweekday()== 6:
        day_now += datetime.timedelta(days=2)
    else:
        day_now += datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return day_now
```

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:**

```
import datetime
def to_week_day(date):
    if date.isoweekday() in set((6, 7)):
        date += datetime.timedelta(days=-date.isoweekday() + 8)
    return date
```

**Explanation:**

I faced this problem today, and @jonrsharpe's answer did not work for me because `date.isoweekday() % 5 = 1` when it's saturday `date.isoweekday() % 5 = 2` when it's sunday, resulting in the next week day being sunday and tuesday respectively, wich is wrong. I didn't wanted to use if statements in the code, so what I did was to find a function y = f(x) that returned y = 2 when x = 6 and y = 1 when x = 7.

This function is `y = -x + 8` and it's used as argument in the timedelta function.

This answer was based on @jonrsharpe's answer so you should upvote him too.

Answer (score 1):

give any day to function get_next_dayofweek_datetime and date_time.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
from datetime import timedelta

def get_weekday(day):
    days  = ["mon","tue","wed","thu","fri","sat","sun"]
    return days.index(day) + 1

def get_next_dayofweek_datetime(date_time, dayofweek):
    start_time_w = date_time.isoweekday()
    target_w = get_weekday(dayofweek)
    if start_time_w < target_w:
      day_diff = target_w - start_time_w
    else:
        day_diff = 7 - (start_time_w - target_w)

    return date_time + timedelta(days=day_diff)

start_time = dt.strptime("2020-02-12 20:20:00", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S") # wednesday


print(get_next_dayofweek_datetime(start_time, "thu"))
print(get_next_dayofweek_datetime(start_time, "fri"))
print(get_next_dayofweek_datetime(start_time, "sat"))
print(get_next_dayofweek_datetime(start_time, "sun"))
print(get_next_dayofweek_datetime(start_time, "mon"))
print(get_next_dayofweek_datetime(start_time, "tue"))
print(get_next_dayofweek_datetime(start_time, "wed"))
print(get_next_dayofweek_datetime(start_time, "thu"))
```

output:

```
2020-02-13 20:20:00
2020-02-14 20:20:00
2020-02-15 20:20:00
2020-02-16 20:20:00
2020-02-17 20:20:00
2020-02-18 20:20:00
2020-02-19 20:20:00
2020-02-13 20:20:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a polynomial function?

```py
import datetime


def weekday_delta_polynomial(x: int) -> int:
    # This polynomial function behaves like this:
    # f(1)=1,f(2)=1,f(3)=1,f(4)=1,f(5)=3,f(6)=2,f(7)=1
    # which can be used to add the amount of days
    # needed from today to next business day
    if not 1 <= x <= 7:
        raise ValueError("Iso Weekday must be between 1 (Mon) and 7 (Sun)")

    polyday = (
        x**6/30 -
        (31*x**5)/40 +
        (169*x**4)/24 -
        (761*x**3)/24 +
        (2957*x**2)/40 -
        (5011*x)/60 + 36
    )
    weekday = int(round(polyday, 0))
    return weekday


def next_weekday(today: datetime.date) -> datetime.date:
    next_iso_weekday_delta = weekday_delta_polynomial(today.isoweekday())
    the_next_weekday = today + datetime.timedelta(days=next_iso_weekday_delta)
    return the_next_weekday


if __name__ == "__main__":
    # Mon -> Tue 2023-06-06
    print(next_weekday(datetime.date.fromisoformat("2023-06-05")))
    # Tue -> Wed 2023-06-07
    print(next_weekday(datetime.date.fromisoformat("2023-06-06")))
    # Wed -> Thu 2023-06-08
    print(next_weekday(datetime.date.fromisoformat("2023-06-07")))
    # Thu -> Fri 2023-06-09
    print(next_weekday(datetime.date.fromisoformat("2023-06-08")))
    # Fri -> Mon 2023-06-12
    print(next_weekday(datetime.date.fromisoformat("2023-06-09")))
    # Sat -> Mon 2023-06-12
    print(next_weekday(datetime.date.fromisoformat("2023-06-10")))
    # Sun -> Mon 2023-06-12
    print(next_weekday(datetime.date.fromisoformat("2023-06-11")))
```