# Is there a way to convert a day name to datetime?

Tags: python, datetime

My csv file has a column with days of the week in Monday through to Sunday. What is the best way to convert these to datetime format? I've tried:

```
datetime.strptime(day, '%A')
```

But get the error:
Time data does not match format '%A'

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?!

Comment: Please show an example of the dataset.

Comment: I am new, I dont know how to do that

Comment: datetime.strptime returns a datetime object, which means you need a full date. What day in the calendar would be just "Monday"? You can use `"%A"` as part of a string containing the actual date, as in `datetime.strptime("2020/10/12 Monday", "%Y/%m/%d %A")`

Comment: If your dataset only has the weekday and what you want is the date of the next of that weekday, then see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26124531/getting-the-date-for-next-weekday).

Comment: @darcamo the problem is, I have no date associated with the day. Just the name of the day.

Comment: In that case, you *have* to assume something to get a proper date (specific day, month, and year), such as the example I mentioned of "the next Monday after some specific date". If you don't really care about the date and all you need is to represent one weekday, then instead of using datetime you can use just use an enumeration.

Answer (score 1):

```
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
print(now.strftime("%A"))
```

You can try this brother, i hope it works well for you

Comment: See the Python docs for datetime.now, datetime.strftime and more on strftime.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have day names, you will have to pick a base date that is the start of 7-day period (e.g. today's date).  From this you can build a dictionary that maps day names with actual dates and then use it to convert the field value:

```
# setup ...
from datetime import *
baseDate  = datetime.today() # current day or some other date (e.g. last monday)
dateOfDay = { dt.strftime("%A"):dt for dow in range(7) for dt in [baseDate+timedelta(dow)] }

# to obtain the date, simply access the dictionary with the day name
dateOfDay["Monday"] 

# print dates for each possible day
for day in dateOfDay:
    print(day,dateOfDay[day].strftime("%x"))
```

If your data spans multiple weeks and is in chronological order, you could advance your baseDate as you go.  This can be achieved by checking if the day's date is lower than the date obtained on the previous entry.  This would signal that you need to move your base date forward by 7 days (`baseDate += timedelta(7)`) and recompute the dateOfDay dictionary from this new date.  Then get the date using the new mapping and resume the data traversal.

*Note that this only works if you never have more than 6 days between entries in your data or if you have some other way to determine week boundaries in your data.*